# c# DataSet select by date doesn't work for the 1st of January

Tags: c#, dataset

I am querying a DataSet by dateFrom and dateTo:

```
var query =  string.Format("Date >= '{0}' AND Date <= '{1}'", dateFrom, dateTo);
var resultRows = myDataSet.Tables[0].Select(query);
```

It works for all possible dates EXCEPT the 1st of January.

Any idea why?

edit:

I tried both:

```
DateTime dateFrom
DateTime dateTo
```

and:

```
string dateFromAsString = dateFrom.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

string dateToAsString = dateTo.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Both times the program doesn't return any data rows for the 1st of January. If I associate the date I am filtering the DataSet on with any other date, but 1st January, the program returns data rows as expected.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: What *doesn't work* mean? You have exception, or unexpected results? If exception, then provide its details. If unexpected results, then add them and results which you are expecting

Comment: Sorry, It doesn't not return any rows of data. There are 4 rows of data for the specified date. If I associate the 4 data rows with a different date (not the 1st of January) the program does return the 4 rows of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem definitely somewhere in your code concerning `dateFrom` and `dateTo`
Sample code below works perfectly, and returns all three rows.

```
var myDataSet = new DataSet();

myDataSet.Tables.Add();
myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Date", typeof (DateTime));
myDataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Value", typeof(string));

myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(DateTime.Today, "1");
myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new DateTime(2014, 1, 1), "2");
myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add(new DateTime(2013, 12, 31), "3");

var dateFrom = new DateTime(2013, 1, 1);
var dateTo = DateTime.Today;

string query = string.Format("Date >= '{0}' AND Date <= '{1}'", dateFrom, dateTo);
var resultRows = myDataSet.Tables[0].Select(query);
```

Comment: I did not specify the type of the Date in DataSet.
Excellent, thank you, it worked :)